# Creating new Log file for each time it enters run() method by ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: logging, java.util.logging, scheduledexecutorservice, log4j

I have been trying and searching for long time like how to create a new log file each time when run() method starts execute using ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.

I have set my job to run for every 30 mins. i want to create new log file name (not to add in the existing log file) whenever job starts at given interval.

there are some examples which gives info about new logs after XXX mins. but my job will run from 0 mins to max (dont know depends upon number of files received for processing).

It would be great if someone help me to find out how to create new log file name each time the run method is called by ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.

thanks a ton.

my code:

```
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE # Define the file appender   
log4j.appender.FILE=com.log.NewLogForEachRunFileAppender # Set the name of the file log4j.appender.FILE.File=C:/LOGS/logs.log     
log4j.appender.FILE.ImmediateFlush=true 
log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=debug log4j.appender.FILE.Append=true 
log4j.appender.FILE.DatePattern='.' yyyy-MM-dd-a 
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
```

Comment: Can you provide examples of what you have tried?

Comment: I am newbie to log4j and Spring, I added the below
# Define the root logger with appender file
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=com.log.NewLogForEachRunFileAppender
# Set the name of the file
log4j.appender.FILE.File=C:/LOGS/logs.log
log4j.appender.FILE.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=debug
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.FILE.DatePattern='.' yyyy-MM-dd-a
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n